Medical information, medication, and medication related alarms, Android app, for patients
Each person has a relationship with hospital information. Hospitals have a clinical record of each person and such information is shared across medical staff in printed format and stored in medical files and also shared telematically. The clinical record includes patient history. Patients may access such information upon request sometimes paying a fee.
However, this is not the primary way in which a patient accesses medical data. In general, a patient is given medical prescriptions / recipes reporting what medication is to be ordered and taken and how it is to be taken, including how often, and medical reports where the levels of various parameters to do with body measurables are reported so that patients and other practicioners such as farmacists and other doctors may reference them.
Sometimes doctors may give medical referrals which are sheets of paper where the need to see another doctor is specified. The medical referrals may also be to set appointments to see the same doctor sometime in the future.
There may also be other documents that are issued by doctors such as certificates of attendance, data to be presented for payment discounts on medication or visits, which may be presented at hospital payment checkpoints, or for illness-related pensions and procedures to be followed to maintain these and so on.
There may also be educational medical information issued upon attending various sites or institutions.
Another type of medical files are booklets issued to parents to keep track of pediatric progress.
Patients may also undergo diagnostical tests and be issued documents with diagnostical information.
All in all, this is a lot of information.
Users will want to have both a file with all this information to keep at home, as well as keep pictures in places such as Google Drive with all of this information. However, being able to store this data within an app to do with medical stuff would be even better.
In fact, if you could also log each appointment, link the documents issued to the appointments, and jot down notes besides each appointment to mention what was discussed, as well as link to pending stuff to review or request from your doctor, in, notes, this would be better.
However, all of this is not all what this post is about. This post deals primarily with the fact that while doctors issue all of this data, patients need an app to manage their medical data and medical to-do business, via, a series of alarms, centered, around a medical app, so that they may be able to focus on something else, for example, their jobs, while not coming down to a neglect of everything they need to do medical-life-wise.
For starters, each patient will have medication to take. This is in fact the main thing, besides diet and lifestyle restrictions, and recommendations, that a doctor may do for you. Let us call this medication “takeables”. The patient will need to keep track of times when takeables are to be taken. This will be true in both those cases where the patient is self medicating as well as for patients that need to be reminded to go to specific places to take these takeables, on time.
So, I am looking for an app that will allow you to track these takeables, and record takeable taking, and keep a log of the takeables and taking panoramic.
So, in the app, the patient should be able to keep a table of stuff to take, with amounts, dates and times at which the stuff is to be taken based on frequency, and keep the revision history of such a table which allows one to see how the various amounts of things to be taken and what to take changes after each blood test.
For each doctor, the app should allow you to record the doctor name, a link to contacts with once or more contact locations and contact information, office times, doctor role name and role notes.
These doctors show up as prescribers in the app, which lists all prescriptions.
In fact, besides a screen with all doctors, the app also has a screen with all medicine names, linked to prescribers, reporting below how to take the medicine and how frequently.
Medicines to be taken together may be linked, together, to the corresponding taking instructions, presented, below.
There is also a screen for pharmacists which links them to contacts.
In the app you can set alarms to schedule a meeting with a doctor for a prescription, so that you will not run out of the prescription needed to get the medication at the pharmacist’s.
An alarm may also be set to context the general practicioner to send an order request at the pharmacy for medication before it runs out, so that you may go and collect the medication at the pharmacist's while some medication is still in the box at home and not yet finished.
In the app you can set with an artificial intelligence (AI) text, a message for the medication, which says, for example, take the medication every three days, or, take this medication on Sunday and the order medication Monday through Saturday. The app records your declaration, attaching it to the medication entity, and displays the dates where the medication is too be taken, in the app calendar, starting from the specified date.
Next to each medication one can also specify a set of dates and locations, also with the AI feature, as to where the person should go to take them at what time and add notes. This may be for pills or medication shots such as immunization shots and so forth.
Next to each medication entity the app should keep shopping details, perhaps with link to the shop website or item in the shopping app used to order it, with details with stuff such as product disambiguation or which products include animal products and which don’t.
Next to each medication entity the user must be able to attach a list of listed side effects, and experienced side effects. Perhaps, even, a medication side effect diary / effect log (even just including possibilty to take camera shots of face or side effects on skin, user may be unable to type due to medication high dosage or disability (in which case camera may be result description useful). All of this is then visible on the app calendar.
The app calendar should have an option to plug into Google calendar as a Google calendar calendar where the information is displayed as the user wishes to toggle the medical calendar on or off.
For each medication, the user must also be able to store information as to where in the household at home the medication is being kept, for easy reference and retrieval.
The app can be tested by just about anyone by doing blood tests and adopting a vitaminic regimen.
Would be nice if after taking, you had the meds taken button, at the bottom of a split screen (created, on purpose, to make room for the med taken button).
It would be nice if the app had per user, accounts (with takableings information). Just like in the Google Calendar app, users could then switch profiles to view takeables and medical data.
Network, storage (and app data sharing, across, family members, could be supported by storing app information in the cloud under Google Drive.
It would be nice to have a medical app for patients and patients’ families that let you keep track of all of this, and listen to alarm reminders, as mentioned.
It would be nice if someone implemented this.
Where can I find such an Android app?
Thanks.

You are writing "All in all, this is a lot of information." and so is your request above. I'd recommend that you try to condensate everything you want to a couple of bullet points in order to get help. "It would be nice if someone implemented this." Software Developers are hungry for money. Give them money and they will implement you almost everything you want. ️
